# How to make a link button with circular borders

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, rounded-corners

I am trying to make a link that looks like a button with a laterally rounded edge, but I need it to be a semi circumference, and I can't do that

the radius ends up changing the diameter of the entire button

I would like the button to look like this

[image: button]

but my result looks like this

```css
a{
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: #999;
}

div{
   padding-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div>
<a>Some text</a>
</div>
```

I needed it to be dynamic, meaning no matter what font size inside it would always have the same rounded shape on the sides

Comment: try using px instead of %

Comment: yeah, it's works I put a massive amount of px to make sure

Comment: why duplicate? the question presented may be the same subject, but it is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with `em` which is relative to the `font-size` (instead of `%` which is relative to the `width`):

```css
a {
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 0.4em 2em;
  background-color: #999;
}

div {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.s { font-size: 10px; }

.m { font-size: 20px; }

.l { font-size: 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="s">
  <a>Some text</a>
</div>

<div class="m">
  <a>Some text</a>
</div>

<div class="l">
  <a>Some text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative unit like `em`.

```css
.rounded-link {
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: #999;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.big {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bigger {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="rounded-link">Some text</a>
<a class="big rounded-link">Some text</a>
<a class="bigger rounded-link">Some text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Copy of the image:

```css
  a {
      border-radius: 2em;
      background-color:#FAFAFA;
      color: #562185;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
    }

    div {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div>
      <a>Some text</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try with `font-size: 240px;`. Or with `font-size: 8px;`. Also working with `rem` instead of `em` is a bad idea because the actual link `font-size` could easily be very different.

Comment: Hmm, You're right, `em` will be a better solution. I'll update